# Should tag definitions be mandatory?

Tags: discussion, tags

I understand that a tag's name should make it clear what the tag is for, but this is often not the case.  For example, we now have *grammar* and *grammaticality*.   Users will probably need to read the tag definitions to decide which one to use.  Myself at least find the explanation text indispensable.  Some tags lack this text, however, so could we make it mandatory to provide one when coining a new tag?  If not I can only hope someone smart and keen will volunteer to go fill in all the missing bits.

Comment: Given that SE is an evolving context, there may be an argument for saying tags should *not* be too closely defined unless and until it becomes apparent in any specific case that the lack of a clear definition is leading to significant confusion or misuse. SE is something of an experiment in the application of 'simulated annealing' to information, and the technique won't work so well if it's too tightly constrained.

Answer (score 1):

Tags descriptions are not mandatory, as they should be provided only for tags that could lead to misuse because the tag is misunderstood, or for tags that have been already misused.

I once found a question on meta.SO about when a tag-wiki is appropriate; I don't find the link right now, but I remember it was reported that not all tags need a wiki.